# Far field of accelerating charge

Tags: visible-light, maxwell-equations

What are the differences between the far field of an accelerating charge in a periodic motion compared to that of a uniformly accelerating charge.

As the periodic motiom has omega in it. which is irrelevant of uniform accelerstion. Also can anyone give me a link to the poynting vector of uniform acceleration.

Questiom inspired by light from a cathode ray and what determines the colour of a charge in uniform acceleration